# Can not open console with virtual machine manager

Tags: kvm

I have two virtual hosts running rhel 8.9 (libvirt-8.0.0) and Virtual Machine Manager (virt-manager-4.1.0) on a desktop to control them.  I built several guests on host1 and everything worked as expected.  I migrated some of them to host2.  Everything works as expected EXCEPt I can not open a console on the migrated guest.  I can start & stop the guests from the VMM; but, when I try to open a console to the guest to change an option (e.g. add a NIC), I get `Host does not support domain type kvm with machine 'pc-q35-rhel8.6.0' for virtualization type 'hvm'`.

If I edit the machine parameter in the xml file from `pc-q35-rhel8.6.0` to just `q35` and save the change, I can then open the console.  If I look at the xml file again, the line still reads `pc-q35-rhel8.6.0`.  If I reboot the host, the problem returns and I have to edit the xml file again.